# Creating multiple properties for different parts of website, or multiple views?

Tags: google-analytics

Installing Google Analytics on my web app. My web app has front facing pages (home, pricing, login, etc.), and the internal app component (dashboard).

What is the generally accepted/practiced way of tracking this kind of a website? Should I create two properties for the two sections of the website, or use one property and create filtered views somehow to separate the two?

Comment: A bit off-topic since it is not a coding question. I suggest asking maybe at webmasters.stackexchange.com. You might also want to make clear if the dashboard is something that is only for site admins or if you expect traffic from users between front facing pages and dashboard. If for any reason you need aggregated numbers for both front and dashboard multiple properties will not work for you, so FWIW I recommend views.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create multiple views for your web app. One view for the non-logged users and other for logged in users. this way it is easier to compare how site visitors and logged in users behave.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even have separate views for the different parts of this website. I would just implement the [User ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en) feature for users that are logged in. That way, the data of logged in users will appear both in your regular views as well as your User ID/cross-device views whereas the data of non-logged in users will only appear in your regular view.

The benefit of this is that you will get cross-device reporting "for free" and you will gain insight into how users switch devices when accessing your app.